# MDS 2012 List members of Product Entity in WCF

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

I need to list member from Production entity in C#.

Below is the code, but I don't know how to build the listing of members attribute e.g. Name from the collection. The code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
// additional references... 
using HelloMDS.MDService; /* for the created service reference */
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; /* supports collection objects used in the proxy */

namespace HelloMDSG_Members
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ServiceClient mdsProxy; /* service proxy object */

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the service proxy 
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
            try
            {
                mdsProxy = CreateMdsProxy("http://localhost/MDS/service/Service.svc");
                Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error connecting: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Call GetMembers");
            GetMembers();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static void GetMembers()
        {


            //declare a new MDS ServiceClient
            ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            //EntityMembersGetRequest request = new EntityMembersGetRequest();

            //Build a request for Entity Members of the Product Entity 
            //in the Product Model, Version 4 from the MDS Sample package on the MS Connect site
            EntityMembersGetRequest request = new EntityMembersGetRequest();
            request.MembersGetCriteria = new EntityMembersGetCriteria();
            request.MembersGetCriteria.ModelId = new Identifier() { Name = "Model 1" };
            request.MembersGetCriteria.VersionId = new Identifier() { Name = "VERSION_1" };
            request.MembersGetCriteria.EntityId = new Identifier() { Name = "Product" };

            request.MembersGetCriteria.MemberReturnOption = MemberReturnOption.DataAndCounts; //without this the request doesn't return memebers !

            Console.WriteLine("Start getting data");

            //submit the request to the MDS Web service  Client
            EntityMembersGetResponse response = client.EntityMembersGet(request);

            Console.WriteLine("Count:{0}", response.EntityMembersInformation.MemberCount);

            //confirm that members were returned
            if (response.EntityMembersInformation.MemberCount > 0)
            {
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Member> members = response.EntityMembers.Members;

                // HELP HERE PLEASE
                // write members list with the name attribute
                Console.WriteLine() member  - name attribute );               

            }

            HandleErrors(response.OperationResult);
        }

        // creates the service client proxy 
        private static ServiceClient CreateMdsProxy(string mdsURL)
        {
            // create an endpoint address using the URL 
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endptAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(mdsURL);

            // create and configure the WS Http binding 
            System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding wsBinding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();

            // create and return the client proxy 
            return new ServiceClient(wsBinding, endptAddress);
        }

        // Handles the operations results 
        private static void HandleErrors(OperationResult result)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            if (result.Errors.Count() != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= result.Errors.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    errorMessage += " OperationResult:Error: " + result.Errors[i].Code + ":"
                         + result.Errors[i].Description + ":" + result.Errors[i].Context.Type.ToString();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "request.MembersGetCriteria.MemberReturnOption = MemberReturnOption.DataAndCounts; //without this the request doesn't return memebers !". This comments saved me and a team member of endless trial and error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
foreach(var member in members)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member.MemberId.Id);
    foreach(var attribute in member.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attribute: {0},\tValue: {1}", attribute.Identifier.Name, attribute.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) I simplified it to:                    foreach (var member in members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Code:{0} Name:{1}", member.MemberId.Code, member.MemberId.Name);
                   
                }

Comment: @publicgk, could you take a look at my question? as I believe it is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548589/mds-wcf-web-service